# Can you identify a manufacturer logo on a connector? Ellipse with inside crossed by two lines forming an arrow

Tags: connector, identification

Does anyone know this manufacturer logo?

It seems to consist of an ellipse with two lines joining at the border of the ellipse.

The part is a SMD barrel connector. We drew the logo and used google image search but weren't successful. Extensive manual search didn't retrieve anything useful either.

I'm sorry for the image quality but the thing is really tiny (6 by 9 mm) and we took the picture with a phone camera through a scale magnifier and couldn't do it better.

[image: barrel connector]

**Addendum**
A second source is of <strike>no</strike> secondary use, because we already have some, but they fail a certification test because the spring forces are too weak. This type of connector used by a competitor doesn't fail the test, so we want to know the manufacturer. Asking our competitor about the type seems no viable possibility :)

**Second Addendum**
Ok, a second source could be of use, I got it.
So here comes the spec:

- Pin diameter is 1.3 mm
- Outer connector diameter is 3.6 mm
- height of connector is 4.71 mm
- Minimum spring force for passing the test is 5 N

And it's really spring force not insertion / extraction force, because the crucial parameter depending on the spring force is the contact resistance.

Comment: With better dimensions in 3D, a Second Source is possible .

Comment: We already have second sources, but they fail certification tests, so we want to know the manufacturer of exactly this one.

Comment: All the more reason to have an acceptable 2nd source

Comment: 2~20N or 3~20N insertion/ extraction spec and what pin size? 5k cycle life And qty/order?

Comment: There are many smaller manufacturers in China and you may find these sold under other names in the West. I doubt you will easily find the real manufacturer. Maybe try ordering a bunchy of sample units from different suppliers (through a distributor) and see if any match yours. It's also possible the re-sellers will change sources if it suits them.

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975: You convinced me. I added the data as far as possible. Cycle life and qty I maybe can add next week as my colleague who might know already left the office.

Comment: Qty=1 won’t even get u a cup of coffee.

Comment: I guess qty is several thousands per year.

Comment: If you rotate it through 180 degrees it looks like the Lexus logo.

Comment: There is a really wide range of force on these parts, for example, CUI  PJ-075DH is 0.3kg to 3kg extraction force, so a "typical" unit would probably pass your 5N requirement, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It's not the extraction force which is required to reach a certain value, it in fact is rather irrelevant for passing the certification. It is really the spring force of 5N we need, which of course is proportional to the extraction force but the latter cannot be calculated exactly because the coefficient of friction varies greatly. And for determining the current capacity only the spring force is of interest.